# cannot find module faker after npm install --save-dev

Tags: node.js, faker.js

I want to install all my modules locally so I am installing everything with the "--save-dev" switch which updates the package.json.

I am trying to include [this](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) module so I installed using this command:

```
npm install Faker --save-dev
```

My app structure is like this:

app
  controllers
  models
node_modules
  Faker
server.js

So Faker is in the right place but when I add this code in my server.js file:

```
var faker = require('./Faker');
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './Faker'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulcowan/projects/async-talk/server.js:23:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

But this works:

```
var Faker = require('./node_modules/Faker');
```

I did not think that I would have to include the node_modules part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your `require` to work, you need do:

```
var Faker = require('Faker');
```

Any package installed by npm is required by name. Only modules that are required locally need a path-like require. Your `require(./Faker);` means *"require a module from the **same directory** as this file, called 'Faker'"*.

Answer (score 58):

After a `yarn upgrade --latest` I got this error for another reason: A `6.6.6` version has been published 13 days ago and it's totally empty ([only one commit called `endgame`](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/commit/2c4f82f0af819e2bdb2623f0e429754f38c2c2f2)): https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker.

Is it a hack? Is it a joke? If yes, is it fun? Not sure...

To fix it simply rollback to the last version.

```bash
yarn add --dev faker@5.5.3
# or if you use npm
npm install --save-dev faker@5.5.3
```

### Edit

Following the answer of `akop` below, the safest way seems to switch to `faker-js`

```bash
yarn remove faker
yarn add --dev @faker-js/faker
```

Then change your imports

```js
import * as faker from 'faker';
// to 
import * as faker from '@faker-js/faker';
```

There is also a type definition for Typescript on their doc but it worked without for me: [github.com/faker-js/faker](https://github.com/faker-js/faker)

### Edit 2

I spoke with the author of the package who's a fun and crazy guy. He got mad because of an intellectual property theft so he kind of destroyed his open-sourced work.

He now develops a 2000s style virtual desktop for fun [buddypond.com](https://buddypond.com/)

Answer (score 20):

I want to mention everyone why this problem happened.
The owner of faker deleted it from GitHub at v6.6.6
You can see that here:
https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/

So it is up to the community to complete it
The new repository:
https://github.com/faker-js/faker

> This is the official, stable fork of Faker.

### Installation

Please replace your `faker` dependency with `@faker-js/faker`.

```sh
npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev
```

### Node.js

```js
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
```

Answer (score 15):

[Faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) (and [colors](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/commit/074a0f8ed0c31c35d13d28632bd8a049ff136fb6#diff-92bbac9a308cd5fcf9db165841f2d90ce981baddcb2b1e26cfff170929af3bd1R18)) was destroyed by the author. [The reason is not totally clear.](https://www.theverge.com/2022/1/9/22874949/developer-corrupts-open-source-libraries-projects-affected)

You can use the version before the endgame-commit (5.5.3), as it already [Jean Claveau described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753878/6537157).
For the future, you should switch to the new community version, it is called **fake-js**. Have a look here: [Github of new faker-js](https://github.com/faker-js/faker)
There is also a faq, which also explains what happens to the old version.

Answer (score 6):

Typescript users coming by, remember to install `@types/faker`. Then, `import faker from 'faker';` works without errors.

Comment: For some people, this will be `import * as faker from 'faker';`

Comment: does that need to be installed as `--save-dev` or a regular install?

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of faker is v7.3.0 .

You should import faker in this way:

`import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';`

This one below doesn't work:

`import faker from 'faker';`

Answer (score 4):

**Genuine solution :**
Roll back to the previous version of the faker i.e. install the 5.5.3 or any lower version. It will work fine.

npm install faker @5.5.3

or

yarn install faker @5.5.3

NOTE : Faker has been changed to fakerjs so if you want to use latest version of faker please install it from fakerjs using the following command :~

npm i @faker-js/faker

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `./`. You're telling Node to look for the module in the current directory.

```
var faker = require('Faker');
```